# Delphi SQLite Cached Updates and Auto-Incremental Fields

Tags: sqlite, delphi, auto-increment, firedac

I am using Cached updates in order to increase speed for my SQLites INSERT queries. The problem I am facing, is that inside the loop where I have my INSERT, I am using an auto-incemental value.

I am using TFDConnection and TFDQuery to implement my database writing part.

Before moving on the next Post()  I need the value of the previous auto-incemental value. The problem is that auto-incremental value is not generated unless in call TFDquery.ApplyUpdates().

SO, is there a way that I can use CachedUpdates but also keep Auto-Incremental values that will be generated after calling TFDquery.ApplyUpdates()?

One idea that came up on my mind, is getting the last generated value with TFDConnection.GetLastAutoGenValue() and calculate how many row I will need. For example if I know that I will insert 5 rows and the last auto-generated value was 300, I know that my next values will be 301,302,303,304,305. The whole problem with this, is that I dont have control on which values correlate with the next Post().

Comment: Why do you need to use AutoInc in this situation, why not just generate a PK value in code and use that?

Comment: I just can't use PK. This is how the database was designed 2 years ago and I have to stick with that. I have to write here all 45 different tables that exist on my database in order to explain why auto_ink is used.

Comment: Does your app have exclusive use of the db?

Comment: On these tables that use auto_increment values it has.

Comment: In that case, you could read the maximum value in the AutoInc column(s) at start-up, then increment it in your app's code by 1 each time you need to do an Insert (and remove the autoinc property on the db column, of course).